# MSBuild /p:BuildProjectReferences=false causes fatal error C1192: #using failed

Tags: msbuild

Currently trying to re-implement our build processes on our build server using MSBuild in place of devenv so that we don't need to have the full VS IDE installed. Having encountered quite a few issues with using MSBuild (race conditions, skipping shared resources instead of blocking, platform inconsistencies between parent and child, etc), I have settled upon building each project in separate tasks one by one to eliminate any concurrency issues and put /p:BuildProjectReferences=false in all the task command line fields to prevent MSBuild from imposing the platform of parent projects upon their heterogeneous children.

It seems however, that when I set this option to false as it is in devenv, MSBuild looks for the dependencies in the the top folder of the parent rather than in the bin as it should. e.g:

ProjectB depends on ProjectA

ProjectA has ..\bin\ProjectA.dll as output.

ProjectB references ProjectA as ..\bin\ProjectA.dll

C:\builds\solution\ProjectB\stdafx.cpp : fatal error C1192: #using failed on 'C:\builds\solution\ProjectB\ProjectA.dll'

**Why does MSBuild check for dependency outputs in the parent project directory instead of the bin and what are the options to resolving this? Any insight is appreciated.**

PS.

After some work I found a partial answer. For C++ I can disable the #using directive pointed at the parent project directory by setting Reference Assembly Output on the project reference in question to false, and then add the path to the Forced #using file field in the parent project configuration under C++ and advanced. This only works for C++ projects though. Still no idea what to do with C# projects.

It appears that MSBuild completely ignores /p:BuildProjectReferences=false when building a C# project, it then attempts to apply a x86 platform to its children, including C++ projects which have a Win32 platform in place of x86, which in turn somehow causes MSBuild to hunt for v100 (VS 2010) build tools that it won't find.

I have since learned a few things about the mechanism in MSBuild that governs this. Apparently there is a MSBuild task called AssignProjectConfiguration, which has a parameter labeled ShouldUnsetParentConfigurationAndPlatform. This is set to true in VS and false in MSBuild. It seems that this would be the source of the resulting configuration/platform mismatch. Why it builds dependencies despite my explicit command-line instructions not to and why the configuration/platform mismatch causes it to look for v100 VS 2010 build tools are both a mystery to me. I have a large log of verbose output to look through. I will endeavor to update this as I continue to read through the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after struggling with this specific issue over the week, not to mention the struggle over the whole host of MSBuild-related problems over the last 4 months, I have elected to go with devenv. Unfortunately, this will fail to decrease our footprint as we had planned to do.

It seems to me that an actual solution is possible using tasks, but the time required to learn and experiment with that framework is likely prohibitive. As of writing this, I am not even sure how to begin manipulating that in order to emulate devenv. The sunk human and time costs are already too high and its time to get something working and move on.

I must admit up front that I am the newest member of my team, but they seem more confused than I am, and they're all seasoned engineers. In their defense, their efforts have been focused elsewhere and have been probably better spent than mine. I have learned a lot though and started to establish my own region of expertise.

I assume that the industry answer to this question would have been to shovel out some more cash to Microsoft for an Azure DevOps instance. I am sure MSBuild works wonderfully in there. Goes to show that you get what you pay for. We'll probably end up there eventually, but barring an unexpected breakthrough, this will have to do for now.